# How to keep track of the coordinates of the turtles after they hit the boundaries of the world in NetLogo?

Tags: distance, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am simulating a random walk within bounded angels, and I want to calculate the [mean squared displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_displacement) of the turtles in 2D in my model. The turtles all start from the center. I am not sure how to update the xy coordinates for the turtles after they hit the boundaries. I am asking the turtles to bounce back when they hit the wall and save their new xcor and ycor. Here's my code:

```
to go
  ask turtles
  [; head in a random direction in range (-theta, +theta)
   ifelse theta = 0 
     [set heading heading + 0 ]
   ; choose a normally distributed random angel in range (-theta, +theta)
     [set heading heading +  random-normal 0 (theta)]

    fd step-size 
    set xc xc + (step-size * dx)
    set yc yc + (step-size * dy)

   ; if your next patch is blocked:
    ifelse not can-move? 1
    [ set heading heading + 180
      fd 1 ]

   ;otherwise:
    [rt random-float random-normal 0 (theta)]
   set xcor xc
   set ycor yc
   set dist sqrt (xc * xc + yc * yc)]
  ]
```

I am getting the error which says:
"Cannot move turtle beyond the worlds edge.
error while turtle 423 running SET
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the grid-wrap disabled and your xcor/ycor of your agents are going past the max-pxcor/min-pxcor and max-pycor/min-pycor

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. I added the condition of  "if can-move? 1" before updating the x-y coordinates and my problem is solved!